# PHP: 'salt' option to password_hash is deprecated

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I'm using password hashing for a registration. I need to create a Salt manually and following is the code I have used:

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)
];
$password = password_hash(
    $this->input->post("confirm_password"),
    PASSWORD_BCRYPT,
    $options
);
```

When I run this code it gives me an error saying:

> password_hash(): Use of the 'salt' option to password_hash is deprecated"

Any solution for this?

Comment: Im using php 7.0.8

Comment: the answer is in the manual

Comment: now you can delete the question

Comment: because the answer is in the manual

Comment: Do not use the salt option.  PHP suggests leaving it to do its own thing.  Just place the cost into the options array.

Comment: what is an manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a solution - don't use the 'salt' option.

You **don't** need to salt manually, PHP does that automatically for you.

It's not an option to add salt, but to replace the would-be-generated one, and under no circumstances would you be able to provide a better salt - that's why it's deprecated.

Comment: What if the thing I need hashed is not a password, but something public, like e-mail? Then to verify the hash came from the email is not enough, because this could be done by somebody's own php script. So I need to verify it was done by my script - am I right in that case I do need salt and that I would just add it to the string, in this case, to the email? 
I notice that then I can't put the code with defined salt on, say, GitHub, but I could make my script generate a file (if not yet exists) with random salt in it so it becomes the domain's signature - does it make sense? Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways to utilize hashing and many factors to consider depending on the use case. I could guess a lot for yours, but one thing is certain - `password_hash()` is not good for your purposes and you should open a separate question ... there's practically no common ground here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'd love if you could clarify why you don't recommend to use it in these cases or point me to other more propper functions..